# Social engine 4 is developed in Zend Framework 2 or in something else?

Tags: zend-framework2

I used social engine 4 just for test and I want to know that Social engine 4 is developed in Zend Framework 2 or in something else? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Social Engine is developed with Zend Framework 1.x